# Installing Windows 98SE without FDD, CD-ROM, Network, or USB on Thinkpad E310ED

Tags: windows-98, laptop, thinkpad

I'm restoring an old Thinkpad E310ed from c. 1997 and running into an issue I can't seem to find a workable solution to: installing Windows 98SE to a new "hard drive." The original HDD seems dead (BIOS detects but drivehead/platters sound awful to the point it's ear-grating) and I've purchased both a 2.5" IDE-CF and IDE-SD adapter. The CD drive in the laptop seems dead as well; it spins up and makes a liquidy sound for about a minute before going idle. Booting from the CD drive has been unsuccessful with every ISO I've tried. There is no floppy drive to make use of. So what I'm left with is the need to install Win 98SE to either a CF or an SD card--through the adapters--and to use that as the disk drive as well. Here's a mostly-complete list of everything I've tried that hasn't worked:

- Booting MS-DOS (installed via Rufus) from the CF drive
- Booting MS-DOS (installed via Rufus) from the SD drive
- Installing Windows 98SE to a similarly-spec'd virtualbox machine, converting to VHD, then using hddguru's raw disk tools to "flash" the virtual Win98SE install to the SD card
- Same as above except I interrupted the Win98SE install right after the copying files to drive step before actual set up begins
- Any and all CD-ROMs will not boot
- Partitioning the SD drive and flashing the Win 98SE ISO to it, then attempting to boot from HDD
- Setting HDD to "none" in the BIOS (this was a fix that worked for some CF card users when it came to older BIOS's not recognizing drive dimensions, like heads and cylinders)

All of the above resulted in the same error: DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER.

Threads reviewed:

- [Installing 98SE without USB/CDROM to IDE drive - Invalid System Disk](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/22335/installing-98se-without-usb-cdrom-to-ide-drive-invalid-system-disk)
- https://superuser.com/questions/1523062/install-win-98-without-cd-and-fdd
- https://www.reddit.com/r/windows98/comments/idsczw/how_would_i_install_windows_98_or_95_osr2_without/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/retrobattlestations/comments/wlmj7x/ways_to_install_windows_98_without_cd_or_fdd/

Responses to Comments (as of 10/31):

- I do not have an extra IDE hard disk, unfortunately. I also do not have any other boot options besides those listed above. There is, annoyingly, no non-proprietary floppy connector (and I cannot find compatible pin-outs for the proprietary external floppy connector). There is also no internal FDD header.
- I had this thought about CD-R compatibility but, unfortunately, do not have access to a pressed OEM CD (the only bootable Win 98SE discs).
- Windows 98SE OEMs were bootable. *See* https://winworldpc.com/product/windows-98/98-second-edition ("Important: Only the OEM Full version is bootable. All others require an appropriate Windows 98 Boot Floppy.").
- The 310ed's BIOS actually explicitly supports boot from CD-ROM which was a surprise! Just too bad the drive is either busted and/or I don't have a compatible CD.
- The error message is definitely from the ROM BIOS as it is present regardless of attached drive.

Comment: If booting MS-DOS from the CF/SD drive didn't work, I'd suspect either incompatibility, or some hardware issue. Can you test with an extra real IDE harddisk? Do you have any other options to boot from besides HD and CD? Does it already have USB? Does it have a floppy connector so you could attach an external floppy drive?

Comment: installing to a virtual machine is nearly impossible, you need to get the chs translation to match, and it never does. 1997 is far too early for USB boot, 1997 era cd drives often (not always) can't read modern CDR, or any after the dye changed to allow 16x writing.  Try a pressed retail win98 CD, or change the cd drive,

Comment: Windows 98 CD's are bookable, but this laptop is you say from 1997, and the first BIOS with CD boot came out around then, so the laptop may or may not have the ability to boot from CD (I'm guessing not). Sadly given that it is near impossible to install windows in another machine and move the disk, re-installing windows is not always even possible on laptops of this era. You may have more luck installing linux, as this does not use chs past the very early boot process. Laptops where re-installing windows is literally impossible exist until the early 00s

Comment: The only idea I have got, is to use another machine to install dos6 or 5 to a cf card, this should be small enough that the chs mismatch shouldn't matter, at least to boot. then you may be able to run the 98 installer off the cd from Dos6. the message non system disk is telling me that it is readlng the disk, but the wrong sectors.

Comment: Problem is, it doesn’t boot at all. The message “DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER” usually comes from the ROM BIOS, which means that it apparently cannot even load a valid MBR from the drive.

Comment: You can try looking at the boot sector of your CF/SD card in another computer: check if it has the 55AA signature, partition table and boot code. Perhaps it’s not the hard drive that’s broken, but the IDE controller. If you can connect the original hard drive to a USB/IDE adapter, you may also see if that works any better than connecting it to the original laptop.

Comment: If you can mount the new drive on a modern machine, you might get away with using Virtualbox and creating a raw virtual disk image (that points to the physical device) - you install it in Virtualbox then move the drive back to the other machine. You'll no doubt get a BSOD and need other drivers etc. but you could put those on the disk ready and safe mode should work.

Comment: Virtual machines will not help when the target computer cannot read the boot sector.

Comment: @MattLacey this is impossible with windows before Vista, as they use chs adressing for booting, and the odds of getting the chs schemes to match are 0, unless you use a machine with an identical bios

Comment: if you actually want to install to a VM, you are going to have to use the laptop bois to determine the CHS the laptop is expecting for that card controller combo (note down the detected CHS settings), manipulate the image so the chs matches, like the guy in this thread did,  https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=63454 and then install to the vm.

Comment: Which CF card it is; or rather, does it have a manual indicating the physical geometry? How large it is, how large a drive your BIOS or DOS can see, what is the geometry that DOS sees after BIOS translation? If the drive is large enough, you could maybe partition it into two partitions, install DOS on first and copy Win98SE install files to second. Then boot to DOS and run Win98SE install.

Comment: @camelccc Ah - it would have worked for me because I was writing a disk image to CF that I took from the original HDD in the machine.

Comment: @MattLacey exactly, the thing that matters is the install is done with the same bios as the machine that is booting - as the roadblock is the CHS translation. Thinking about this, I don't think even manipulating the CHS of the image is likely to work, as the CHS translation scheme needs to match. If there is a USB port at all, most bios will emulate a usb floppy disk as a regular floppy during startup, so a USB floppy drive is usually (exceptions exist) bootable, even if usb sticks or CD drives are not.  Failing this, the only way is to clone a disk from a machine with a similar enough bios

Comment: Not sure of the specifics of the E310ED, but I had a couple Thinkpads from the same era (760XD). The internal CD-ROM bay doubled as a floppy disk bay, you just needed to have the drive to swap in. Maybe you can find one on eBay.

Comment: If you want to test the hardware, you can install or make a bootable linux image to the CF card. Unlike Windows this does not use CHS at all during the boot phase, and is much more portable, so should boot barring a hardware compatibility problem. This will of course get you no closer to installing windows.

Answer (score 2):

Put the hard drive (or flash card) in another computer. With all storage devices being broken it is the only way. Obtain a Windows 98SE start up disk or earlier DOS boot disk, or boot from your CD. Run fdisk and then format the drive. run sys c: to make the drive bootable assuming it is drive c.

What size is the SD card in the SD drive? The original SD card readers before SDHC cannot work with an SD card over 2GB. It is a hardware limit. Does the BIOS recognize the presence of the drive? It should detect it and show you the size, otherwise it is not working.

The "other computer" can be a VM. Make sure you know what hard drive CHS values the virtual BIOS in the VM is presenting to DOS. Some older BIOS have bugs with larger hard drives.

If you get past that part successfully most of the work is done since that is the hard part. The CHS values of both computers must match or else the CHS in the partition table and the CHS stored at the beginning of the bootable partition won't match the BIOS and it won't boot. You can probably turn translation on (8.4GB limit) or off (504 or 528MB limit) on the Thinkpad. The same on the other computer. They need to match. If the Thinkpad doesn't support extended INT 13h then you'll have to have translation enabled or you'll have the 528MB limit, and Windows 98 won't fit. Same applies if you use an old version of DOS that doesn't support extended INT 13h. You have to obtain the boot floppy or boot off the CD. I assume the Windows 98 CD boots in to DOS. I haven't used one before.

Once you have bootable DOS working, it's a simple matter of copying the win98 directory on to the drive before moving it over to the Thinkpad and running win98\setup.exe from inside DOS. Make sure the drivers to get networking going are copied as well, because a network share, direct serial cable connection, or infrared (if equipped) are going to be the only ways to copy files over.